# Req.check() not processing the validation in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, validation, backend

I have the following code for password validation in my nodeJS application:

```
  // check for password

  console.log("Testing One") // First print statement

  req.check("newPassword", "Password is required").notEmpty();
  req
    .check("newPassword")
    .isLength({ min: 6 })
    .withMessage("Password must be at least 6 chars long")
    .matches(/\d/)
    .withMessage("must contain a number")
    .withMessage("Password must contain a number");

  console.log("Testing Two"); // Second Print Statement
```

Below is the code for the request body that the above code needs to process:

```
{ resetPasswordLink:
   'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJfaWQiOiI1ZTlhZjg4YzN',
  newPassword: 'testingPassword101' }
```

So when I'm validating the newPassword which happens to be inside `req.body` with the help of the above-given password validation code, then it just keeps on processing the request without returning back any response. For example, in the validation code above, the first print statement gets executed but the second print statement doesn't get executed which means that the code gets stuck when performing the validation on the `newPassword` field of `req.body`.

I'm not able to make out as to why this is happening. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: can you show how you defined the validation middleware for the route? At the moment, it seems like that `.check()` is after the middleware declaration since `req` is accessible.

Comment: Here it is: `Router.put("/reset-password", passwordResetValidator, resetPassword);` where `passwordResetValidator` is the middleware performing the validation on the given password.